# A doubly-continuous knapsack problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

is this sort of maximization problem understood?

Take a function $f:\mathbb{R}_+^n\to \mathbb{R}_+$ increasing in each dimension, differentiable, bounded above by some constant $C$. (possibly not concave). Fix $v\in\mathbb{R}^n_+$.
\begin{align} 
    \text{maximize }\ & \int f(x)\mu(dx) \\
    \text{over }\ & \mu \text{, a distribution on } \mathbb{R}_+^n \\
    \text{subject to }\ & E_\mu[x]=v.
\end{align}

Comment: What do you mean by understood ?

Comment: I think it is reducible to the ordinary continuous knapsack problem. In fact I think it might have a closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a finite point mass result that uses Caratheodory's theorem.

---

Define 
$$A = \{(x, f(x)) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} : (x_1, ..., x_n) \geq 0\}$$
Let $X$ be any nonnegative random vector and assume $E[X]$ and $E[f(X)]$ are both finite. Then $(X,f(X)) \in A$ always, and so,
$$ E[(X, f(X))] \in Conv(A) $$
where $Conv(A)$ is the convex hull of the set $A$.

Fix $v=(v_1, ..., v_n)$ as a vector with positive entries. We want to maximize $E[f(X)]$ subject to $E[X]=v$. This is equivalent to
\begin{align}
\mbox{Maximize:} \quad & y \quad (Eq. 1) \\
\mbox{Subject to:} \quad & x=v \quad (Eq. 2)\\
& (x,y) \in Conv(A) \quad (Eq. 3) 
\end{align} 
For simplicity assume a solution $(x^*,y^*)$ exists.  Since $(x^*, y^*) \in Conv(A)$, and $A$ has $n+1$ dimensions, Caratheodory's theorem ensures $(x^*,y^*)$ can be written as the convex combination of at most $n+2$ points in $A$.  However, since $(x^*, y^*)$ is on the *boundary* of $Conv(A)$, a simple extension to Caratheodory ensures $(x^*,y^*)$ can be written as a convex combination of at most $n+1$ points in $A$, so there are probabilities $p_1, ..., p_{n+1}$ that sum to 1, and nonnegative vectors $x_1, ..., x_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that: 
$$(x^*, y^*) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} p_i(x_i, f(x_i)) $$
That is, we define an optimal random variable $X^*$ to take the value $x_i$ with probability $p_i$, for $i \in \{1, ..., n+1\}$, and this solves the problem. $\Box$

Comment: Note: If you define $-g(x)$ as the "convex hull" of $-f$,  then the problem reduces to a convex program of maximizing $g(x)$ subject to $x=v$.

Comment: Great, and now it is the ordinary continuous knapsack problem. Thanks

Comment: @enthdegree : I'm not sure what is meant by the "ordinary continuous knapsack," wikipedia gives a different description that still has only a finite number of items, but allows you to place fractional values.  Not the same as this. That is an easier convex program.  The problem here is more difficult and the "convex hull" operation is not trivial.  It can be shown that a Lagrange multiplier vector exists for this problem, but in multidimensions that is not so helpful.  Modifying the constraint to $E[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i] = v \in \mathbb{R}$  is easier as we can use a single Lagrange multiplier.